# Python: Compare two dictionaries and write identical entries in both into a separate file

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-2.7

I have two tab-delimited files. The number of lines in the files are not the same. I've put the first two columns of each files into dictionaries. I want to get the identical (key, value) pairs in both files into a separate output file.

for example

```
dict1 = {'sim3_orf00006': 'gi|224475510|ref|YP_002633116.1|', 'sim3_orf00005': 'gi|224475511|ref|YP_002633117.1|'}
dict2 = {'gi|224475987|ref|YP_002633593.1|': 'sim2_orf00909', 'gi|224477510|ref|YP_002635116.1|': 'sim1_orf00452'}
```

File1:

```
sim2_orf01946    gi|224475611|ref|YP_002633217.1|    100.0
```

File2:

```
gi|224475496|ref|YP_002633102.1|     sim3_orf00019   100.0
```

update: Thank you all for responding

Answer (score 5):

Use intersection of the sets with `(key, value)` pairs:

```
with open('output_file', 'w') as f:
    for key, value in set(dict1.items()) & set(dict2.items()):
        f.write("%s\t%s" % (key, value))
```

Comment: Works fine as long as value is hashable

Comment: @JonClements, yes, in this case both values are string (hashable).

Answer (score 1):

No need to create temporary sets in memory. Dictionary already provides `O(1)` lookup complexity:

```
dict1 = {'a':'b', 'c':'d'}
dict2 = {'c':'d', 'e':'f'}

filtered = ((item,value) for (item,value) in dict1.iteritems() if item in dict2 and value==dict2[item])
with open('output_file', 'w') as f:
    for key, value in filtered:
        text = '{}\t{}'.format(key, value)
        print(text)
        f.write(text)
```

`value==dict2[item]` will only be calculated if `item in dict2` returns `True` because `and` is a [shirt-circuit operator](http://docs.python.org/library/stdtypes.html#boolean-operations-and-or-not).

Also, it's important to note that the complexity of this solution for `n` length of the first dictionary and `m` length of the second dictionary is `n` iterations by `O(1)` lookup in the second dictionary, giving `O(n)`. So, if `m` is smaller than `n`, it's worthwhile to swap dictionaries, so the complexity would become `O(m)`.

Using `set` won't do any better, as [set intersection `s&t`](http://wiki.python.org/moin/TimeComplexity#set) has `O(min(len(s), len(t))` complexity.

So, this approach will decrease memory footprint leaving the complexity the same.

Answer (score 1):

You could use:

```
for key, d1v in dict1.iteritems():
    try:
        if d1v == dict2[key]:
            pass # it's a match
    except KeyError as e:
        pass # no corresponding key
```

Or, if the overlap is expected to be low, then pre-compute the keys to be compared:

```
for key in (dict1.viewkeys() & dict2.viewkeys()): # use .keys() in 3.x
    if dict1[key] == dict2[key]:
         pass # match
```

Comment: From what I read, raising exception is quite costly. And in this solution they will occur all the time when the value from the 1 dictionary is missing in the second one.

Comment: @ovgolovin Good point - it's simplest if heavy overlap is expected, otherwise, subsetting the keys to look at is probably more suitable

Comment: The second one is a great solution. And I think it even can be refined by using `viewitems`. I wonder what is the time complexity of `dict1.viewitems() & dict2.viewitems()`.

Answer (score 0):

This will write to your third file, ONLY the key, value pairs that are present in both `dict`s. However, if you want the entire line from the original files, you will need to deal with that differently. One possible way of doing so would be to add those lines directly into your `dict` for a faster lookup

```
outfile = open('path/to/output/file', 'w')
for k,v in dict1.iteritems():
    if k in dict2 and dict2[k]==v:
        outfile.write('\t'.join([k,v]) + '\n')
outfile.close()
```

Hope this helps

Comment: small typo in line 3, should be: `if k in dict2...`

Comment: @BioGeek: Thanks for the bug report. Fixed!

Answer (score 0):

```
A = {}
B = {}

# put stuff in them

for key in A.keys():
    if key in B.keys() and A[key] == B[key]:
        #write to file
```

or

```
shared_keys = [key for key in A.keys() if key in B.keys() and A[key] == B[key]]
with open("path/to/file", 'w') as writer:
    for key in shared_keys:
        writer.write("Key: %s, A: %s, B: %s" % (key, A[key], B[key]))
```

Comment: First one is incorrect: `B` can contain items with the same key but a different value as in `A`.

Comment: @BioGeek i missed they have to be identical. will reflect in code.